# Create an in-app hyperlink on iOS using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, frontend

I want to develop a feature that allows users to visit a website in the app, and the hyperlink is attached to images. The picture below is what I expect to see (copyright: coinbase wallet). This picture depicts what will happen when a user clicks through the URL, he/she is able to browse the website entirely on my app instead of switching to Safari.
[image: coinbase wallet app gallery]

Remember, I want the motion totally on the app, so SwiftUI's component **Link** does not seem to work. So what can I do? Also, is it possible to attach a link to any content other than plain text?

Comment: Look up `SFSafariViewController` for an in-app Safari experience. If you want more customizability than that, look up `WKWebView`

Comment: you could use "universal links" to open your App, and also the ".onOpenURL{...}" to attach to any content.  See this article: https://brunoscheufler.com/blog/2020-12-13-supporting-universal-links-with-swiftui

Comment: You guys' ideas both sound great, but is it possible to click through to a website on a tab instead of a button?

Comment: @MemphisMeng I'm not sure what that means. Do you mean you want the web view to be a tab in, say, a SwiftUI `TabView`?

Comment: I made it, no worries! It turns out that I just need to insert an image into my button component!